# PyTorch Installation Question:PyTorch 0.4.1 - CUDA 9.2 on Windows 11

Tags: python, pytorch

My understanding of deep learning is limited, so I hope to learn it through PyTorch. I prefer to start with an older version of PyTorch.

I downloaded and installed `CUDA 9.2` on Windows 11 , and my CUDA driver version is `CUDA 12.1`

```
nvcc -V

nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2018 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Tue_Jun_12_23:08:12_Central_Daylight_Time_2018
Cuda compilation tools, release 9.2, V9.2.148
```

Initially, I tried to install `PyTorch 0.4.1` with `CUDA 9.2` using the following command:

```
conda install pytorch=0.4.1 cuda92 -c pytorch
```

The output was:

```
Solving environment: failed
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:
  - pytorch=0.4.1*
```

Unable to resolve this issue through Conda, I opted for a **manual installation**.
Subsequently, I downloaded the wheel file `cu92/torch-0.4.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl` from https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html.

I created a Conda environment with `Python 3.6.5` and installed `cudatoolkit 9.2`.

However, when I ran the following code:

```py
import torch

print("PyTorch Version:", torch.__version__)
print("CUDA Available:", torch.cuda.is_available())
print("CUDA Version:", torch.version.cuda if torch.cuda.is_available() else "N/A")
```

The output was:

```
PyTorch Version: 0.4.1
CUDA Available: False
CUDA Version: N/A
```

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

I'm asking a question on Stack Overflow for the first time. If I unintentionally offend anyone, I sincerely apologize in advance.